# Javascript Login Page

Tags: javascript, html

So I have a login script I made but I want it so when a user logins in successfully they go to a page set for that said user for example that users profile page
How would I achieve this?

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
var count = 2;

function validate() {
    var un = document.myform.username.value;
    var pw = document.myform.pword.value;
    var valid = false;

    var unArray = ["Philip", "George", "Sarah", "Michael"];
    var pwArray = ["Password1", "Password2", "Password3", "Password4"];

    for (var i=0; i <unArray.length; i++) {
        if ((un == unArray[i]) && (pw == pwArray[i])) {
        valid = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (valid) {
        alert ("Login was successful");
        window.location = "http://www.google.com";
        return false;
    }

    var t = " tries";

    if (count == 1) {t = " try"}

    if (count >= 1) {
        alert ("Invalid username and/or password. " +
               "You have " + count + t + " left.");
        document.myform.username.value = "";
        document.myform.pword.value = "";
        setTimeout("document.myform.username.focus()", 25);
        setTimeout("document.myform.username.select()", 25);
        count --;
    }

    else {
        alert ("Still incorrect! You have no more tries left!");
        document.myform.username.value = "No more tries allowed!";
        document.myform.pword.value = "";
        document.myform.username.disabled = true;
        document.myform.pword.disabled = true;
        return false;
    }

}

</script>

<form name = "myform">
  <p>
    ENTER USER NAME <input type="text" name="username">
    ENTER PASSWORD <input type="password" name="pword">
    <input type="button" value="Check In" name="Submit" onclick="validate()">
  </p>
</form>
```

Comment: What is the "BLAH..." part?

Comment: What is your problem! What do you mean Blah ?!

Comment: not really sure what you are asking, but you should be doing password validation server side, not in javascript. Look on google for some examples

Comment: Could you describe your environment - which web framework are you using?

Answer (score 1):

First I can't answer this without stating that Philip, George, Sarah or Michael wont thank you for making their passwords visible in this way:

```
var pwArray = ["Password1", "Password2", "Password3", "Password4"];
```

As others have said: If you were to code a page like this there is no point in using passwords as they would be visible to all users of the page.
However given the method you have used so far, you could do the following

```
var pwLocation = ["location1", "location2", "location3", "location4"];
window.location = pwLocation[i];
```

Answer (score 0):

Creating Login page using javascript is not secure because since javascript is client side scripting, any user can see what the code looks like using the page source, so if you need to make login pages you better learn Server side scripting languags like PHP.

To answer you question :

Use if statment to redirect each user to specific page based on their user name , for example if username is 'jamson' then redirect jamson to his own page using the location where his page is found. 
still this method is ardous if you have thousandth of users.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't do this via JavaScript. It's highly insecure as users can view-source, and can find a list of usernames.

To answer your question though, change the line that says: `window.location = "http://www.google.com";`, to `window.location = un.toLowerCase()+".html";`.